# CSS: Correct behaviour of min-height in combination with margin & padding

Tags: css

Currently I'm working on a website for myself. I decided to go for a header content footer design where the footer shall be stuck to the bottom all the time. Hence I set up a wrapper with position: relative, containing the header (#top), content (#middle), and footer (#bottom). Bottom got position: absolute with top: 0.

I've also set height: 100% for html and body and a appropriate padding-bottom for #middle to ensure that my footer won't overlap #middle.

Please find a simplified sample version here: http://www.webdevout.net/test?0w

Here is the CSS in question:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {height: 100%}

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ccc;
    min-height: 100%; 
}

#middle {
    background-color: #900;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
}

#top, #bottom {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #bb5;
}

#bottom {position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
```

Now here's my problem: my understanding of the box-model is, that one should be able to achieve the same (keeping the space for the footer) with margin-bottom instead of padding-bottom for #middle, but margin-bottom isn't applied to it. I've read that min-height doesn't consider padding, border or margin, but the padding is considered here while border and margin aren't.

FF and Chrome show different behaviors when margin-bottom is used instead of padding-bottom for #middle: while Chrome just ignores the margin, FF applies it below #wrapper. My general idea would have been that my container should grow to the total size of its content with min-height, including height + padding + border + margin of #middle, but obviously it just grows to overall size of #top + height of #middle + padding of #middle.

I wonder what is the correct behavior and why padding and margin aren't interchangeable to keep the space for the footer.

While an explanation would be much appreciated, I'd be also thankful for a link to a source which could help me. I'm sorry if this duplicates another post, but I didn't find something (neither here nor via Google) fitting my special problem.

Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you posted some relavent code right in your post. Footer stuck to the bottom means that it is always visible no matter where you scroll on the page, or that it is at the very bottom of the page and you only see it when you scroll right down?

Comment: Hello! Sorry, since it's my first post here I just don't wanted to spam with to much and thought it would be a good idea to use a pastebin which already shows the sample. Stuck to bottom means that it is always at the very end of the page, so that you have to scroll down if there's more content than space on the page.

Comment: No worries. The questions that get the best answers here on SO tend to be concise, clear and contain a simplified code example. I think that you haven't gotten much attention here because your question is fairly wordy and most people won't bother deciphering it. Posting a fiddle or a code sample is great to demonstrate code, but it is encouraged to include a sample in the post directly for ease of reading (not to mention in case the link ever dies).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I'll try to keep my questions shorter and more to the point in the future. Since I don't want to duplicate this question and it might be to late to get much attention for this question: do you also have an idea this behaves like it does? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem as you are facing.

You have to use this piece of code.

```css
#middle {
  display: table;
  margin: 2% auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

use of `display : table` works for me to set the margin from top and bottom.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, but I'm afraid it doesn't work. I applied it just as you've posted it and the margin between #top and #middle (margin-top of #middle) is set while the margin of 2%, which should be set as margin-bottom for #middle, is still ignored (by Chrome).